# NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

*Код*:

```
try:
    import vk_api
    from colorama import init, Back, Fore, Style

except ImportError:
    os.system('pip install vk_api')
    os.system('pip install colorama')

init()


class data():
    token = '' #токен юзера
    index = 1 #не трогаем данные пункт (с какого юзера начнется рассылка [list id])
    chatid = 912 #ид чата 
    chatids = [None] #Список ид чатов(при chatid = None)
    timewait = 2 #задержка 
    message = '''Made by blinchikdev''' #сообщение

    def get_users(api):
        users = api.messages.getChatUsers(chat_id=self.chatid, chat_ids=self.chatids)

    def send(api, users):
        api.messages.send(chat_id=users[self.index], random_id=0, message=self.message)
        self.index += 1
        time.sleep(self.timewait)

def main():
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=data.token)
    api = vk_session.get_api()

    try:
        data.get_users(api)
        users = data.get_users(api)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)

    try:

        while data.index != len(users):
            data.send(api, users)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)


main()
```

*Ошибка*:
name 'self' is not defined.
local variable 'users' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_users(api):
    users = api.messages.getChatUsers(chat_id=self.chatid, chat_ids=self.chatids)
```

В этой функции и другой у вас пропущен аргумент self, указывающий на собственный экземпляр класса. Всегда ставьте его первым. Правильно будет так:

```
def get_users(self, api):
```

И во второй точно так же.

И рекомендую писать все данные конкретного экземпляра класса в его конструкторе, а не напрямую в теле класса, то есть в `__init__`. И название класса с большой буквы пишите.

users у вас нигде не сохраняется, он как был локальной переменной, так и остается. Нужно писать self.users, если хотите запрашивать его значение вне функции, и так с любым полем класса.